# Broken Python script that triggers an Arduino via Twitter

Tags: python, api, twitter, arduino

since Twitter changed their APi the script I have to control a prototype vending unit doesn't work anymore, and the developer who wrote the script has moved on to greener pastures.

The script scans Twitter once every 15 seconds searching for the most recent tweet that contains a specified hashtag (currently set to #sunshine) and it also filters out any retweets.

When it has identified a new tweet, it sends a signal to an Arduino which triggers a solenoid to dispense a free product sample (currently sunscreen)

this line of code appears to be the problem/obsolete:

```
j =json.loads(urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+searchTerm+'&result_type=recent&rpp=1&filter:retweets').read())
```

I've registered a Developer account with Twitter, so I have the consumer secret and token codes etc. but I still don't know how to modify the old code with these OAuth codes to get it working again. I have reproduced the code in full below. Can anyone please help me and show me the way to get this script working again.

```
import twitter
import json
import urllib
from pprint import pprint
import time
from arduino import Arduino

##################SETUP AS REQUIRED###########################
##############################################################
#Change to suit the sample, currently at 0.2 of a second  #
vendtime = 0.2                                               #
                                                         #
#Delay Time Between each Search (never below 15 seconds)     #
delayTime = 15                                               #
#This is the search term for the URL. (%23 = #)              # 
searchTerm = '%23sunshine'                      #
                                                         #
A = Arduino('COM3') #This will need to be COM3              #
A.output([12]) #Output on pin 12                             #
A.output([13]) #to keep serial in use                        #
##############################################################


#to collect the first tweet without vending
countTweet = 0
#To test Twitter for consistancy 
tweet= 0
noTweet= 0



#the infinite loop
while True:

    #j contains the JSON we load from the URL
    j =json.loads(urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+searchTerm+'&result_type=recent&rpp=1&filter:retweets').read())

    #Debug JSON from twitter (for faults on the Twitter end or possible GET limit id below 15 seconds per request)
    #pprint(j) #needed for debugging only

    #find the text and the tweet id
    if 'results' in j and j['results']:
        text = j['results'][0]['text']
        id = j['results'][0]['id']
        #how many times the Json is complete
        tweet+= 1
    else:
        #How many times the Json is incomplete (sometimes twitter malfunctions. About 0.1 in 100 are broken)
        noTweet += 1

    #print the text and id to the screen
    pprint(text) #needed for debugging only
    pprint(id)   #needed for debugging only

    #to get the existing tweet from before we power on, if the first ID has been stored already (count == 1)
    if countTweet != 0:  #if countTweet is not equal to 0 then it's not the first tweet
        #pprint ("new loop") #needed for debugging only

        #if lastID is not equal to ID
        if lastID != id:
        #Tell Arduino to Vend
            #pin 12 HIGH
            A.setHigh(12)
            #Sleep for the time specified in vendtime
            time.sleep(vendtime)
            #pin 12 LOW
            A.setLow(12)
            #Display the tweet that triggered the vend
            #pprint(text) #needed for debugging only
            #pprint(id)   #needed for debugging only
            #Make lastID equal to ID so that next time we can compare it 
            lastID = id
            #pprint ('lastID updated') #needed for debugging only
        #if no new tweets, print     
        else:  #needed for debugging only
            pprint ('no new tweets') #needed for debugging only
    #If it's the first loop, confirm by printing to the screen
    else:
        pprint("First loop complete")
        pprint(text)
        pprint(id)
        lastID = id
        pprint(lastID)
        countTweet += 1 #Add 1 to countTweet

    pprint ('Number of Tweets')
    pprint (countTweet)
    pprint('Working JSON')
    pprint(tweet)
    pprint('Broken JSON')
    pprint(noTweet)
    pprint('waiting')
    A.setHigh(13)
    time.sleep(delayTime)
    A.setLow(13)
```

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

Comment: yeah I read that link before, so I know about the OAuth codes. But that link doesn't give me a step by step explanation on how to use them. Imagine I'm a five year child who can just about operate a keyboard. That's the kind of step-by-step help I'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted didn't even use the [twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter%20twitter) library. The code below has been reworked and actually uses the twitter library but you still need to put the twitter keys into the code.

```
from twitter import *
import time
from arduino import Arduino

##################SETUP AS REQUIRED###########################
##############################################################
#Change to suit the sample, currently at 0.2 of a second     #
vendtime = 0.2                                               #
                                                             #
#Delay Time Between each Search (never below 15 seconds)     #
delayTime = 15                                               #
#This is the search term                                     # 
searchTerm = "#sunshine"                                     #
                                                             #
A = Arduino("COM3") #This will need to be COM3               #
A.output([12]) #Output on pin 12                             #
A.output([13]) #to keep serial in use                        #
##############################################################

# Twitter keys
OAUTH_TOKEN = ""     # Access token
OAUTH_SECRET = ""    # Access token secret
CONSUMER_KEY = ""    # Consumer key
CONSUMER_SECRET = "" # Consumer secret

#to collect the first tweet without vending
first_tweet = True
#To test Twitter for consistancy 
tweet= 0
notweet= 0

# Start Twitter session
t = Twitter\
(
    auth = OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
)

#the infinite loop
while True:
    # Print stats
    print("Number of Tweets: %d" % (tweet + notweet))
    print("Working JSON: %d" % tweet)
    print("Broken JSON: %d" % notweet)

    # Perform search
    search_results = t.search.tweets(q = searchTerm, _timeout = 60)

    #find the text and the tweet id
    tweet_failed = True
    if search_results:
        if search_results.has_key("statuses"):
            statuses = search_results["statuses"]
            if statuses:
                # Select first result
                status = statuses[0]
                if not bool(set(["id", "text"]) - set(status.keys())):
                    tweet_failed = False
                    tweet_text = status["text"]
                    tweet_id = status["id"]
                    #how many times the Json is complete
                    tweet+= 1
    if tweet_failed:
        #How many times the Json is incomplete (sometimes twitter malfunctions. About 0.1 in 100 are broken)
        notweet += 1
        continue
    else:
        if first_tweet:
            first_tweet = False
            print("First loop complete")
        else:
            #if last_id is not equal to tweet_id
            if last_id != tweet_id:
                #Tell Arduino to Vend
                #pin 12 HIGH
                A.setHigh(12)
                #Sleep for the time specified in vendtime
                time.sleep(vendtime)
                #pin 12 LOW
                A.setLow(12)

        #Make last_id equal to ID so that next time we can compare it 
        last_id = tweet_id
        #Display the tweet that triggered the vend
        print("Tweet: %s" % tweet_text)
        print("Id: %d" % tweet_id)

    print("waiting")
    A.setHigh(13)
    time.sleep(delayTime)
    A.setLow(13)
```

Comment: Hi dilbert, thank you very much, I managed to get it working. I had to clear the Pyhon/Lib of a lot of various twitter libraries and files with the name twitter in them. I then reinstalled Python and did an easy_install twitter and now it works. This script still requires some refining and further development and I don't have the time or the skills to do it. Would you be willing to work on this from time to time if I was to pay you? please email me at jayprout@talktalk.net and thanks again - Jay

Comment: Do you have any conceptual ideas about what you want changed ? Perhaps it might be a better idea to find a local programmer to make those changes, as some of those changes might require modification of the Arduino code.

Comment: Hi @dilbert the main issue is that the internet connection is 3G and can be very erratic. When the connection goes down the script will crash and can't recover when the connection is restored. I have to manually reboot the PC. Another issue is that Retweets are not filtered out, I would like the unit to vend only when asend a trigger signal for unique tweets, not retweets. I would also like to restrict the trigger to a local

Comment: I would also like to restrict the vend to tweets that are local, and if possible I would like an auto reply to the sender of the tweet with a "thank you for tweeting enjoy your free sample" Would you be interested in working on this? the crash recovery is the main thing that requires fixing,  jayprout@talktalk.net